# PHP : preg_replace function for replace unicode chracters with range in a string

Tags: php, unicode, preg-replace

I want to remove a set of characters from string. I am using preg_replace for replace unicode character with blank.

I have some ranges for unicode characters.

It works for following code.

```
$output = "Clean :this; [cnv\al?id@ non AS]CII äóchar^acters.";
$output = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F]|[\x21-\x2C]|[\x3A-\x40]|[\x5B-\x5E]|[\x7B-\x7D]|[\x80-\xBF]|[\x2B0-\x36F]/','', $output); 
echo $output;
```

But it gives error for following code.

```
$output = "Clean :this; [cnv\al?id@ non AS]CII äóchar^acters."; 
$output = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F]|[\x21-\x2C]|[\x3A-\x40]|[\x5B-\x5E]|[\x7B-\x7D]|[\x80-\xBF]|[\x2B0-\x36F]|[\x2000-\x2BFF]|[\x2E00-\x2E7F]|[\x3000-\x303F]|[\x1D000-\x1D24F]|[\x1F600-\x1F77F]|[\x1F000-\x1F0FF]/','', $output); 
echo $output;
```

Error:- preg_replace(): Compilation failed: range out of order in character class at offset 97

I can use for loop for remove unicode characters from string. So I need to run loop for more range.

Can you please suggest me which is better in above code? Either for loop or preg_replace? If preg_replace is better then need solution for above error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `\x` will accept two digits only, so you need to add curly brackets, like:

```
$output = "Clean :this; [cnv\al?id@ non AS]CII äóchar^acters."; 
$output = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F]|[\x21-\x2C]|[\x3A-\x40]|[\x5B-\x5E]|[\x7B-\x7D]|[\x80}-\xBF]|[\x{2B0}-\x{36F}]|[\x{2000}-\x{2BFF}]|[\x{2E00}-\x{2E7F}]|[\x{3000}-\x{303F}]|[\x1{D000}-\x{1D24F}]|[\x{1F600}-\x{1F77F}]|[\x{1F000}-\x{1F0FF}]/u','', $output);
```

-with that you'll also need to add `u` modifier to your regex.